# Updating objects in an array is often failing RavenDB

Tags: ravendb

Iterating through a result set and updating is often failing to persist the update

```
if (actionObject.ActionType==ActionType.TradeComplete)
        {
            var results = _session.Query<Model.ActionObject>().Where(x => x.ActionType == ActionType.TradeRequest && x.ActionObjectId==actionObject.ActionObjectId);
            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                result.State = State.Closed;
            }
        }

        _session.Store(actionObject);
        _session.SaveChanges();
```

Often, the object is not getting its state set to state.closed..

I see the discussion around patch commands, but there's little to no documentation on how to do that with a query that has multiple parameters..

Any idea why it isn't persisting?

Edit: my object does not have an ID, could that be the problem? It seems Raven is supposed to track the objects, and often is...

Comment: What do you mean, failing? What is the actual problem?

Comment: HI Ayende, I mean that the object is not being updated. After the above code I then load the object and it's value has not been updated to 'CLosed'. This is also true if I check using the studio. The object has not been updated.

Comment: Ah HA!The update wasn't failing.. what was failing was the query to get the object TO update.  Clearly the previous write (where the object was created) wasn't completed yet.  I added `.Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfNow())` to the select query, and were good to go.